# Add multiple items to a listbox on the same line

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Hey guys, i figured out how to add items to a listbox one line at a time:

```
try
{
     if (nameTxtbox.Text == "")
            throw new Exception();

     listBox1.Items.Add(nameTxtbox.Text);
     nameTxtbox.Text = "";
     textBox1.Text = "";
     nameTxtbox.Focus();
}
catch(Exception err)
{
     MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Enter something into the txtbox", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

But I wont to be able to add multiple items to the same line. Like have first_name |
last_name | DoB all on the same line. When I do

```
listBox1.Items.Add(last_name.Text);
```

It adds the last name to a new line on the listbox, I need to add it to the same line as the first name.

Comment: The `ListView` supports displaying multiple columns, it may be what you're after...

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you still want to add one "item", but you want it to contain more than one piece of text. Simply do some string concatenation (or using `string.Format`), eg.

```
listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} | {1}", first_name.Text, last_name.Text));
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually you don't want to include multiple columns into a `ListBox`, because ListBox is meant to have only one column.

I think what you're looking for is a ListView, which allows to have multiple columns. In a ListView you first create the columns you need

```
ListView myList = new ListView();
ListView.View = View.Details; // This enables the typical column view!

// Now create the columns
myList.Columns.Add("First Name", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
myList.Columns.Add("Last Name", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
myList.Columns.Add("Date of Birth", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Right);

// Now create the Items
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(first_name.Text);
item.SubItems.Add(last_name.Text);
item.SubItems.Add(dob.Text);

myList.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score -3):

Here has a solution to add multiples items at the same time.

```
public enum itemsEnum {item1, item2, itemX}

public void funcTest2(Object sender, EventArgs ea){
    Type tp = typeof(itemsEnum);
    String[] arrItemEnum = Enum.GetNames(tp);
    foreach (String item in arrItemEnum){
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: this makes no sense, why do you have Object sender, EventArgs ea in your solution...  also see @EMP's solution below, that's the answer.