# Adding multiple items to a windows form ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am trying to create a basket where the user enters a product, how many they want and a price per product and I want it to display in a list box like a basket. The current code I have only inserts the product (first column)

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = product;
item.SubItems.Add(quan2);
item.SubItems.Add(price2);
```

Comment: [Check this it may helps you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896723/add-multiple-items-to-a-listbox-on-the-same-line)

Comment: Make sure your ListView `View` property is `Details`

Comment: @BaliC I think it has been working all along and that just saved me a lot of time thank you, its fixed

Comment: @kieronoates Nice one, I did think your code looked ok :)